# Can I combine red & black wire from ceiling to black wire on remote reciever

Tags: wiring, ceiling-fan

[image][image][enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QPKLu.jpg)

I have 2 switches on wall, 4 wires from ceiling. The ceiling fan I purchased only has 2 wires to be hooked up. Can I combine the red & black wires from ceiling to black wire to remote receiver?

Comment: How do you want the wall switches to work?

Comment: Yes. I would like both switches to work.

Comment: Is changing to a different remote system an option?

Comment: What is the model number of the fan?

Comment: You could have both switches work, but then the remote could only control either the fan or the light. You would just bypass the remote control unit for power to the other one.

Answer (score 1):

No. You currently have 2 separate switches...1 for fan on/off and 1 for light on/off, correct? You need to cap either one, red or black, and remove the switch associated with that wire and cap the wires at the old switch location. Best bet is cap the red off, and remove that switch. You could replace the switch in your 2-gang box with an electrical outlet, or just get a new face plate that only has one switch opening.

Comment: Guys, Thanks for the replies. Yes. I have to switches. I would like both of them to work instead of going through the hassle of changing them. Do I have any other easy options to get both switches to work?